# How can I get a link to call me with Microsoft Teams for personnal use

Tags: microsoft-teams, meetings

I need to participate in a virtual meeting with some business. They told me (via email):

> please give us a link so we can connect to you

They also told me they use Microsoft Teams.

I downloaded Microsoft Teams and installed it on a Windows 10 computer. I tried to connect it to a Microsoft account but when asked if it's for personnal, professional or school use (I said personnal use) I just get "for personnal use, please use Skype", so back to square one.

I tried the mobile version on my Android smartphone and was able to connect* a Microsoft account for personnal use.

However, I don't know how to generate the link they need.

I would like to avoid requesting the business I need to talk to for technical support because they are lawyer so their time is very expensive.

---

(*) Why does it work on mobile but not on desktop? This is a mystery to me but this is not my question. If there's a way to make it work on desktop, please advise because I would really like to use a larger screen.

Comment: [This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-link-or-a-code-for-joining-a-team-11b0de3b-9288-4cb4-bc49-795e7028296f?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#:~:text=If%20you’re%20a%20team%20owner%2C%20go%20to%20the,any%20browser%20to%20join%20the%20team.%20See%20More) might be helpful.  Have you tried just logging your Microsoft Account into Teams?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't have those options. Not sure what "Team owner" is but I don't think i'm one. If I log in my Microsoft account into Teams on the computer, I get "you are not using Teams, get it here", then I'm asked if it's for personnal use and if I say yes I just get a message telling me to use Skype.

Answer (score 0):

If they use Microsoft Teams they can easily send you a meeting link where you can join them into a call on your PC via the browser (or mobile). No need for you to install MS Teams or have a MS account.

This would be much easier to go the other way around (they send you a link) then how they are requesting.